# Filter log messages by program name and log level at the same time in rsyslogd

Tags: logging, rsyslog

I want to save log messages from program `foobar` with log level `err` into file `/var/log/foobar.log` in rsyslogd. How can I do that?

This is how I can filter messages by program name:

```
:programname,contains,"foobar" /var/log/foobar.log
```

This is how I can filter messages by log level:

```
*.err /var/log/foobar.log
```

But I don't understand how to filter by both these filters at the same time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This example on the rsyslogd wiki](https://web.archive.org/web/20180330104136/http://wiki.rsyslog.com/index.php/Filtering_by_program_name) suggests a way to do something like you want. It's the **Filtering by program name using the expression-based syntax** part.

Using the example provided on the wiki:

```
if $programname == 'foobar' and $syslogseverity-text == 'error' then /var/log/foobar.log
```

Put that on rsyslogd.conf or as a snippet inside rsyslog.d

Comment: Please add a summary to your answer.

Comment: Thank you! Where can I find list of all variables like $programname and $syslogseverity-text?

Comment: I found it on this list: http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/property_replacer.html

Answer (score 3):

a simple way to do that is ... if ( $program contains "foobar" ) and ( $severity contains "err" ) then /var/log/foobar.log

Of course there are many other ways, but i think that the above is quite straight forward.

Comment: I like this syntax, but it doesn't work in version 8 (Debian 10).